# Preventing duplicate mongoDB entries

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoDB with a mongoose schema:

```
const newsSchema = new Schema({
   serverid: Number,
   resetid: Number,
   newsid: Number,
   timestamp: Number,
   type: Number,
   win: Number,
   attacker_num: Number,
   attacker_name: String,
   defender_num: Number,
   defender_name: String,
   result1: Number,
   result2: Number,
   a_tag: String,
   d_tag: String,
   killhit: Number
});
```

Below is what the CSV api looks like that I insert into my mongoDB:

> ```
> 9,672,22697434,1408587629,5,1,351,LaFing at SoF,9,ReDflag,10,0,SoL,LaF,0
> 9,672,22697435,1408587629,5,1,377,Commorragh,9,ReDflag,10,0,PDM,LaF,0
> 9,672,22697436,1408587629,5,1,589,The IX Kiss,9,ReDflag,10,0,SoL,LaF,0
> ```

Field #3 is unique from the api, it is never duplicated. In my schema it is called newsid. If my script were to update the database from the feed and it tries to insert another row that contains a newsid that is already in the database, is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

A [unique key constraint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) would do exactly what you want.

The unique key can be set in [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html) with either the schema field options:

```
const s = new Schema({newsid: {type: Number, unique: true}});
```

or by the [`index`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-unique) method:

```
Schema.path('newsid').index({unique: true});
```

If an attempt is made to create a document that already has an entry for that key then an error will be thrown:

> NOTE: violating the constraint returns an E11000 error from MongoDB when saving, not a Mongoose validation error.

Comment: If an error is thrown will it still attempt to insert the other records that are not duplicates or does it stop the entire insert process.  I insert 10,000 lines at a time and lets say 5,000 of them are duplicates and 5,000 are not.  Will it only insert the 5,000 that are not duplicates?

Comment: @Ryansworld84 That depends on how you implement the insertions. The unique key constraint doesn't control how insertions are made.